# How to increase an integer variable with another integer variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, integer

What I need is to increase the value of a variable dynamically (within a loop) by another variable. Here is my code:

```
while read  Plate City Town Village Area Population; do
    echo "$Plate $City $Town $Village $Area $Population"
    
     printf "\n$totalNumberOfTowns\n " 
     totalNumberOfTowns=$totalNumberOfTowns+$Town
     totalNumberOfVillages=$totalNumberOfVillages+$Village

done < "cities.txt"
```

what I get when I run my code is a little bit not-correct.
[image]

I didn't understand why there is  "Town" inside $totalNumberOfTowns variable. Another interesting part is it also does calculation(it sums third parameter which is number of town in that city. For ADANA it is 15 and for ADIYAMAN it is 9 and so on.).

## **Edit:**

First line of cities.txt is:

Plate   City    Town    Village Area    Population

see screenshot:
[image]

## **Edit-2:** # I have tried these different syntaxes:

```
let "totalNumberOfTowns+=$Town" #1 I tried these different syntaxes
totalNumberOfTowns=$((expr $totalNumberOfTowns + $Town)) #2
totalNumberOfTowns=$((totalNumberOfTowns + Town)) #3
```

Yet, each of them gave me some errors.

Here are sample cities.txt and sample code:

Plate   City    Town    Village Area    Population
1   ADANA   15  508 14030   2258718
2   ADIYAMAN    9   420 7614    632459
3   AFYONKARAHİSAR  18  395 14230   736912
4   AĞRI    8   566 11376   535435
5   AMASYA  7   352 5520    335494
6   ANKARA  25  711 25706   5663322
7   ANTALYA 19  545 20723   2548308
34  İSTANBUL    40  166 5196    15462452

**code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

average=0
numberOfCities=80

declare -i totalNumberOfTowns=0 totalNumberOfVillages=0
arrayWithOut=""

while read  Plate City Town Village Area Population; do
    echo "$Plate $City $Town $Village $Area $Population"

    printf "\n$totalNumberOfTowns\n " 
      totalNumberOfTowns+=$Town
     totalNumberOfVillages+=$Village

done < "cities.txt"
```

Comment: If your file has a header line you'd have to read that first instead of trying to do math on a value like "Town" instead of a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ignore first line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

average=0
numberOfCities=80

declare -i totalNumberOfTowns=0 totalNumberOfVillages=0
arrayWithOut=""

{
read -r first_line
while read -r Plate City Town Village Area Population; do
    echo "$Plate $City $Town $Village $Area $Population"

    printf "\n$totalNumberOfTowns\n " 
      totalNumberOfTowns+=$Town
     totalNumberOfVillages+=$Village

done 
} < "cities.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use variables with [an integer attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i totalNumberOfTowns=0 totalNumberOfVillages=0

while read Plate City Town Village Area Population; do
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" "$Plate" "$City" "$Town" "$Village" "$Area" "$Population"
    totalNumberOfTowns+=$Town
    totalNumberOfVillages+=$Village
done < "cities.txt"

printf "Total towns: %d\nTotal villages: %d\n" "$totalNumberOfTowns" "$totalNumberOfVillages"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the expression in double parenthesis for example `$((your_expression))`

```bash
while read  Plate City Town Village Area Population; do
    echo "$Plate $City $Town $Village $Area $Population"
    
     printf "\n$totalNumberOfTowns\n " 
     totalNumberOfTowns=$((totalNumberOfTowns + Town))
     totalNumberOfVillages=$((totalNumberOfVillages + Village))

done < "cities.txt"
```

Comment: when I do this I get en error says: line 14: Town: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "Town")

Answer (score 0):

I know even three ways to calculate in bash:

#### Command expr (operators: +, -, *, /, %, (, ); and logic operators: <, <=, ==, !=, >=, >)

expr 2 * 3 (the spaces and '' sign before operator are important)

or

a=5; a=$(expr $a + 1)

#### Syntax (( <expression> )) - all operators known in C language

a=0; a=$((a+1))

#### Command let

x=0; let "x += 2"

Comment: you sum one variable and one integer. Is it the same with two integers? Because when I try your style I still got en error.

Comment: I tried : totalNumberOfTowns=$((expr $totalNumberOfTowns + $Town)) and got an error

Comment: These are three different ways that you shouldn't mix.  totalNumberOfTowns=$((totalNumberOfTowns + Town)) shall be enough.

Comment: If you still have any error we need more information.

Comment: when I try with this I get :  Q1: line 14: Town: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "Town")

Answer (score 0):

And a viable (and most likely quicker) `awk` alternative.

```
awk '
NR==1{print} 
NR>1{a+=$3;b+=$4;print}
END{
  print "Total number of towns:",a
  print "Total number of villages:",b
}' cities.txt
```